# Which Audio Format would be best for me to store audio files on Android Smartphone?

Tags: android, audio, apk, android-music-player, audioformat

I am developing an Android based application which plays Audio Files from an Album. The audio files in the album are all in **MP3 Format** with **Audio BitRate 320 KBPS**. Since there are 18 songs in the album and the average song size is 6MB, my Android APK size is **approx 110MB**.

I wanted to ask which Audio Format would be best for me which reduces the APK Size without significantly reducing the Audio Quality ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html AAC has good quality on lower bitrates

Comment: Yah I've found 50% size reduction in my apk file when I use AAC format instead of MP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best used are aac and mp3 I prefer mp3 but Shahab is right aac would work